# Angular not showing results in browser

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am taking an angular class online and finding challenges on how to use ng-init it displays the same code in my html when opened in the browser.Please i need assistance on how to solve this issue. I tried changing the angular version in the JSON file but it did not work.Thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
         content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content">
                  ng-init="
                         dish=
                         {
                           name:'Uthapizza',
                           image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                           category: 'mains',
                           label:'Hot', 
                           price:'4.99',
                           description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comment: ''
                        }">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                     <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                        <a href="#">
                        <img class="media-object img-thumbnail"
                         ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                         <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                         <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span></h2>
                        <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                              <p>Comment: {{dish.comment}}</p>
                        <p>Type your comment:
                         <input type="text" ng-model="dish.comment"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've placed the `ng-init` directive in the body of the `div`.

The directive should be inline with the `div` tag as shown below:

```
<div class="row row-content" ng-init="dish={}">

</div>
```

Also, I do not see an `ng-app` directive.  You will need this in your body to allow AngularJS to hook into your application, this is placed before the `ng-init` directive.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="">

  <div class="row row-content" ng-init="dish=
                         {
                           name:'Uthapizza',
                           image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                           category: 'mains',
                           label:'Hot', 
                           price:'4.99',
                           description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comment: ''
                        }">

    <p>
      {{dish.name}}
    </p>
    
    <p>
      {{dish.category}}
    </p>

  </div>

</div>
```

I have also created a **JSFiddle** for you to demonstrate this working:

https://jsfiddle.net/65LaufpL/

As an additional note you may want to look at AngularJS controllers and store the `dish` variables within that as it would be much cleaner than using the `ng-init` directive.

Comment: Thank you it worked.The ng-app directive is placed in <html lang="en" ng-app> after the !DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the `ng-init` directive as attribute of the div tag.

```
<div class="row row-content" ng-init="dish={
     name:'Uthapizza',
     image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
     category: 'mains',
     label:'Hot', 
     price:'4.99',
     description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
     comment: ''
}">
```